# Calculate distribution of $X$.

Tags: probability

The time student Anne spent waiting for a school bus has geometric distribution with expectation 10 minutes.  Anne can be playful little girl and can sometimes miss a bus so she needs to wait for next.  The probability of Anne getting into the bus is $p$. Let $X$ be a random variable representing the time Anne spent at the station until she boarded the bus.
Calculate distribution of $X$ and $\mathbb{E}X$.

What is the best method for solving this? Is it by using generating functions (I tried that way but I got stuck)?

Comment: Do you mean "exponential distribution" whete you put "geometric distribution"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be i.i.d. exponential random variables with $\mathbb E[X_1]=1/\lambda$ and $N\sim\mathrm{Geo}(p)$ be independent of the $X_n$. Then $X=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$. For each $n\geqslant 1$ the distribution of $X$ conditioned on $N=n$ is given by
$$
f_{X\mid N=n}(t) = \frac{(\lambda t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\lambda e^{-\lambda t},
$$
and so the distribution of $X$ is given by
\begin{align}
f_X(t) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{X\mid N=n}(t)\mathbb P(N=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\lambda t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}p(1-p)^{n-1}\\
&= \lambda p e^{-\lambda t}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\lambda t(1-p))^n}{n!}\\
&= \lambda p e^{-\lambda t}e^{\lambda t(1-p)}\\
&= \lambda p e^{-\lambda pt},
\end{align}
i.e. $X$ has an exponential distribution with mean $\mathbb E[X_1]=1/\lambda p$.